# Find a specific text segment within a file and than search for specific line in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I'm trying to find a specific text segment within a text file and than a specific line within the text segment. The algorithm should be as follow:

1)First, search for a line which contains the keyword "Macros"

2)The next found line  must contain the keyword "Name"

3)And finally print me the next line

As  pseudo code I mean something like this:

```
File.open(file_name) do |f|
  f.each_line {|line|
    if line.include?("Macros")
      and if next line.include?("Name")
        print me the line after
    end
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use boolean flags to remember that I already matched the parts of the condition:

```
File.open(file_name) do |file|
  marcos_found = false
  name_found   = false

  file.each_line do |line|
    if line.include?('Macros')
      marcos_found = true 

    elsif found_marcos && line.include?("Name")
      name_found = true

    elsif marcos_found && name_found
      puts line
      break # do not search further or print later matches
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Your solution looks simple and I tried it already. The interesting is that it found only the first string (in this example "Macros"). I tested it so that I put "puts line" directly below "macros_found = true" . But nothing is outputted with the last "puts line" . Any idea?

Comment: @milexy86 : I updated my answer. You have to define the flag variables outside of the iteration, otherwise they were just visible in one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex:

```
r = /
    \bMacros\b  # Match "Macros" surrounded by word breaks
    .*?$        # Match anything lazily to the end of the line
    [^$]*       # Match anything lazily other than a line break
    \bName\b    # Match "Name" surrounded by word breaks
    .*?\n       # Match anything lazily to the end of the line
    \K          # Discard everything matched so far
    .*?$        # Match anything lazily to the end of the line
    /x          # Extended/free-spacing mode
```

Suppose:

```
text = <<-_
You can use
Macros in C
to replace code.
Ruby doesn't
have Macros.
"Name That Tune"
was an old TV
show.
_
```

Let's write this to file:

```
FName = "test"
File.write(FName, text)
  #=> 104
```

read it back into a string:

```
str = File.read(FName)
  #=> "You can use\nMacros in C\nto replace code.\nRuby doesn't\nhave " +
  #   "Macros.\n\"Name That Tune\"\nwas an old TV\nshow.\n"
```

and test the regex:

```
text.scan r
  #=> ["was an old TV"]
```